# Fill a table with custom model

Tags: lightning-aura-components, table

I am new to lightning experience and I am trying to write a table that is filled via a button, when you click the button it calls js which calls helper and that calls an apex class which takes an opportunity id and returns a list of products, I have a custom class within the apex code called product which has extra information in it. I'd like to return the product model and fill my table in my component with that data, I have tried so many different things that I can't possibly explain what I've done, but I feel that I am very close to a solution. When I click my button the console shows a series of `[object Object],[object Object],...` and my table is spitting out empty rows, what do I need to do to fix this so it works?

**Component:**

```
    <aura:attribute name="products" type="Object[]" />

    <div class="slds">
        <h1 class="main-header header-text">Product Component Tab</h1>
        <section class="main-section">
        <h4 class="sub-header header-text">Test grid power</h4>
        <section class="main-section">
            <section class="sub-section">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Code">Product Code</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">Product Name</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Unit Price">Unit Price</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Current Filter">Current Filter</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration var="product" items="{!v.products}">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!product.ProductCode}">{!product.ProductCode}</div>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!product.ProductName}">{!product.ProductName}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!product.UnitPrice}">{!product.UnitPrice}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!product.AppliedFilter}">{!product.AppliedFilter}</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="align-right" style="display:block;">
                    <ui:button aura:id="gridFiller" label="Fill this table!" press="{!c.FillIt}" />
                </div>
                <lightning:spinner aura:id="ajaxLoader" variant="brand" size="large" class="no-vis" />
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
({
    FillIt : function(component, event, helper){
        helper.getProducts(component);
    }
})
```

**Helper.js**

```
({
    getProducts: function(component){
        var spinner = component.find("ajaxLoader");
        var action = component.get("c.getProducts");

        action.setParams({ opportunityId : "006q0000007KyVn" });
        $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "no-vis");

        // Create a callback that is executed after 
        // the server-side action returns
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "no-vis");
            // This callback doesn't reference component. If it did,
            // you should run an isValid() check
            //if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // Alert the user with the value returned 
                // from the server
                //alert("From server: " + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue())));
                //aura attributes can only accept arrays or lists, loop through returned value to create an array.
                component.set("v.products", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log('What is in products attribute: ' + component.get("v.products"));

            }
            //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
                console.log("incomplete");
            }
            //else if (cmp.isValid() && state === "ERROR") {
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    alert('An error has occurred, please see console log.');
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        // optionally set storable, abortable, background flag here

        // A client-side action could cause multiple events, 
        // which could trigger other events and 
        // other server-side action calls.
        // $A.enqueueAction adds the server-side action to the queue.
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class LightningProducts {

    public class Product {

        public Id OpportunityId;
        public Id OpportunityLineItemId;
        public Id ProductId;
        public Double Quantity;
        public String ProductName;
        public String ProductCode;
        public Boolean Active;
        public Double UnitPrice;
        public Double ExtendedPrice;
        public Boolean IsCommonItem;
        public Boolean IsCommonSosItem;
        public Boolean IsRecorded = false;
        public Boolean IsUpdate = false;
        public String AppliedFilter;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Product> getProducts(String opportunityId){
        Opportunity opp = [select Id, PriceBook2Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: opportunityId];
        Id pricebookId = [select Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE Id =: opp.PriceBook2Id].Id;

        List<Product> pList = new List<Product>();
        List<PricebookEntry> priceBookEntries = new List<PricebookEntry>();
        String filter = GetFilter();

        if(filter == ''){
            priceBookEntries = [select Id, Name, IsActive, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, ProductCode, Product2.Common_Items__c, Product2.Common_Items_SOS__c, UnitPrice, UseStandardPrice 
                            from PricebookEntry 
                            where isActive = true and Pricebook2Id =: pricebookId];
        } else {
            priceBookEntries = [select Id, Name, IsActive, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, ProductCode, Product2.Common_Items__c, Product2.Common_Items_SOS__c, UnitPrice, UseStandardPrice, Product2.SCRIBE_Product_Type__c
                            from PricebookEntry 
                            where isActive = true and Pricebook2Id =: pricebookId and Product2.SCRIBE_Product_Type__c =: filter];
        }

        for  (PricebookEntry pbe : priceBookEntries) {
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.OpportunityId = opportunityId;
            prod.ProductId = pbe.Product2Id;
            prod.ProductName = pbe.Name;
            prod.ProductCode = pbe.ProductCode;
            prod.Active = pbe.IsActive;
            prod.UnitPrice = pbe.UnitPrice;
            prod.IsCommonItem = pbe.Product2.Common_Items__c == 'Yes';
            prod.IsCommonSosItem = pbe.Product2.Common_Items_SOS__c == 'Yes';
            prod.AppliedFilter = filter;

            pList.add(prod);
        }

        return pList;
        //return JSON.serializePretty(pList);
    }



    private static String GetFilter() {
        // Custom product filter based on user profile - e.g. when TSS user is logged in, the product list would automatically filter to just "service" products.
        Id profileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
        Profile p = [select Name from Profile where id =: profileId];
        String profileName = p.Name;
        String filter = '';

        if(profileName == 'srvc1')
            filter = 'Services';
        else if(profileName == 'srvc2')
            filter = 'Services';
        else if(profileName == 'srvc3')
            filter = 'Services';
        else if(profileName == 'System Administrator')
            filter = 'Kit';

        return filter;
    }
}
```

First and foremost I'd like to know how to get this to work with my apex class returning a `list` or whatever but If I could do something to return `JSON` from my apex class that would be very beneficial as well.

Thank you.